# How to update Hazelcast map frequently

Tags: java, groovy, hazelcast

I am using Hazelcast 2.0.1 to update data frequently (some 2mins), which includes first deleting and then loading data from DB. However somewhere down the line, one of the thread holds a lock on a key, which prevents delete operation and throws an exception (`java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: Another thread holds a lock for the key: abc@gmail.com`). Please help me in way that my maps in hazelcast gets updated.

I am giving my code below

DeltaParallelizer

```
def customerDetails = dataOperations.getDistributedStore(DataStructures.customer_project.name()).keySet()
ExecutorService service = Hazelcast.getExecutorService()

def result
try{
    customerDetails?.each{customerEmail->
        log.info String.format('Creating delta task for customer:%s',customerEmail)
        def dTask = new DistributedTask(new EagerDeltaTask(customerEmail))
        service.submit(dTask);
    }
    customerDetails?.each {customerEmail ->
        log.info String.format('Creating task customer aggregation for %s',customerEmail)
        def task = new DistributedTask(new EagerCustomerAggregationTask(customerEmail))
        service.submit(task)
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

EagerDeltaTask

```
class EagerDeltaTask implements Callable,Serializable {
    private final def emailId
    EagerDeltaTask(email){
        emailId = email
    }
    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        log.info(String.format("Eagerly computing delta for %s",emailId))       
        def dataOperations = new DataOperator()
        def tx = Hazelcast.getTransaction()
        tx.begin()
        try{
            deleteAll(dataOperations)
            loadAll(dataOperations)
            tx.commit()
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            tx.rollback()
            log.error(String.format('Delta computation is screwed while loading data for the project:%s',emailId),e)
        }       
    }

    private void deleteAll(dataOperations){
        log.info String.format('Deleting entries for customer %s',emailId)      
        def projects = dataOperations.getDistributedStore(DataStructures.customer_project.name()).get(emailId)
        projects?.each{project->
            log.info String.format('Deleting entries for project %s',project[DataConstants.PROJECT_NUM.name()])
            def srs = dataOperations.srs(project[DataConstants.PROJECT_NUM.name()])?.collect{it[DataConstants.SR_NUM.name()]}
            def activitiesStore = dataOperations.getDistributedStore(DataStructures.sr_activities.name())
            srs?.each{sr ->
                activitiesStore.remove(sr)
            }
            dataOperations.getDistributedStore(DataStructures.project_sr_aggregation.name()).remove(project[DataConstants.PROJECT_NUM.name()])
        }       
        dataOperations.getDistributedStore(DataStructures.customer_project.name()).remove(emailId)
    }

    private void loadAll(dataOperations){
        log.info(String.format('Loading entries for customer %s',emailId))
        def projects = dataOperations.projects(emailId)
        projects?.each{project->
            log.info String.format('Loading entries for project %s',project[DataConstants.PROJECT_NUM.name()])
            def srs = dataOperations.srs(project[DataConstants.PROJECT_NUM.name()])
            srs?.each{sr->
                dataOperations.activities(sr[DataConstants.SR_NUM.name()])
            }
        }       
    }   
}
```

DataOperator

```
class DataOperator {
def getDistributedStore(String name){
    Hazelcast.getMap(name)
}
}
```

I get exception in deleteAll srs, so some of the maps content is deleted and new data is loaded only for the map whose content was deleted and rest of the map has old data. So I am not getting updated data in my Hazelcast map. Please suggest your views on how can I get updated data into my Hazelcast map.

Also does this `Hazelcast.getTransaction` client works for this purpose?

Note: customer can have many project_num, 1 project_num can be shared by multiple customers too
        1 project_num can have multiple SR_NUM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used [Hazelcast  eviction policy](http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/2.0/manual/multi_html/ch02s03.html#MapEviction) which **solved** my problem. I used a `<time-to-live-seconds>300</time-to-live-seconds>` which clears map content every 5 minute and when any request comes from UI for any map it reloads that map content from a loader.

Below is one of the Hazelcast map config

```
...
<map name="customer_project" >
    <map-store enabled="true">
        <class-name>com.abc.arena.datagrid.loader.CustomerProjectData</class-name>
    </map-store>
    <time-to-live-seconds>300</time-to-live-seconds>
</map>
...
```

`CustomerProjectData` loader class simply loads data into map from DB. So now I no longer need `DeltaParallelizer` or `EagerDeltaTask` class

Different approaches are also welcome :)